# Can I scroll up one app from another app?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have an Android app which can overlay arbitrary other apps. I was just wondering,is it possible to scroll up the underlying app from the new app, or is this not allowed?

Comment: I think this depends on how much space your app takes up on the screen. If it's just a bubble head like facebook messenger has the underlying app will be able to scroll..but if it's a large portion of the screen.. It will have focus and would have to be dismissed before the underlying app can scroll